# Using old windows disk as storage. Is there any reason to reformat it?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, formatting, storage

I just upgraded my main hard disk to an SSD. I installed and re-activated Windows 10 on the SSD. Now I have a old hard disk that I want to use as storage. It already has some files that I want to keep. So I was thinking that I can just delete all the Windows-related folders and start using it for purely storage. For example, I could delete the following files (outlined in red) and keep the "Users" folder which has the files that I want to keep.

[image: Windows hard disk contents]

However, there was at least one article I found that mentioned reformatting the disk without explaining why. So that left me curious. **Is there any particular reason to reformat an old hard disk before using it as storage?**

Comment: After you verify the EFI partition is actually on the SSD and not the HDD you can format the HDD if you want.

Comment: @Ramhound I installed Windows 10 while the hard disk was disconnected so it should be on the SSD. But my question was: can't I just delete the windows folders instead of formatting?

Comment: You can remove the files however you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real harm in leaving the drive as is, however, there are some minor benefits of reformatting:

- you have the opportunity to run a full read/write test to ensure the disk has no bad sectors
- moving the files off the volume and back to a freshly formatted volume will reset the permissions.
- you can repartition the drive to reclaim any space used by hidden system partitions
- moving the files will also defrag them

**Edit:** Also, by formatting without first backing up the files you get a chance to test your backup plan ;-)